# Search for a specific tweet containing specific words by a specific person using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Afternoon everyone! I was just wondering if anybody had suggestion for my title. I know there are many twitter library's out there on npm, but I'm not sure what is the best one to use for what I'm trying to do. 
In better sentences, I'm trying to find a specific tweet by a person (*Specified by username*) and then check it to see if it contains certain text. I'm sure I can use the normal twitter API, but I'm having some trouble with that. If anybody could supply an example on how to do this that would be great! 
Using the "Twit" package on npm, I saw this example which might work for my needs, but I'm unsure how to make it to one user.

```
//  search twitter for all tweets containing the word 'banana' since July   11, 2011
//
T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 100 }, function  (err, data, response) {
console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has lots of [advanced search operators](https://twitter.com/search-advanced).

The one you want is `from:`

For example to find every tweet I've sent which contains "banana" you would use

`'banana from:edent since:2011-07-11'`